# Как найти сумму целых отрицательных чисел массива и найти количество чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 1 Python

Tags: python

Есть такой массив

```
a = [-1.1, -1, 0.1, 1, -2.1, -2, 0.2, 2, -3.1, -3, 0.3]
```

из него с помощью цикла for **(и без numpy)** надо вывести:

1. Сумму целых отрицательных чисел: `(-1)+(-2)+(-3) = -6`
2. Количество чисел в диапазоне `0..1`: `0.1, 0.2, 0.3 = 3`

Я новичок в `Python` и уже как не пытался, могу только найти сумму всех отрицательных чисел, но ЦЕЛЫХ отрицательных не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сумма целых отрицательных чисел:

```
b = sum(x for x in a if type(x) == int and x < 0)
print(b)
```

Сумма целых отрицательных чисел c filter:

```
d = sum(filter(lambda x:  isinstance(x, int) and x < 0 , a ))
print(d)
```

Колличество чисел от 0 до 1:

```
c = sum(1 for x in a if x<1 and x>0)
print(c)
```

Comment: Почему-то вывод: -3

Comment: тип переменной лучше проверять при помощи функции `isinstance(x, int)` )

Comment: а в чём отличие между type и isinstance?

Comment: Для конструкции `x for x in ... if ...` в питоне придумана такая штука как `filter`, правда там придётся `lambda` писать, не все это любят )

Comment: @CrazyElf, в такой задачи с `filter` код более длинным получается :)

Comment: можно чуть покороче `c = sum(x for x in a if 0 < x < 1)`

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил пример с filter

Comment: @Zhihar К сожалению, да. И это печально, так то `filter` прекрасен )

Comment: c = sum(**1** for x in a if x<1 and x>0) - там нужно количество

Comment: @MBo спасибо, исправил

Comment: @CrazyElf lambda часто не подходит, когда дополнительно надо индекс итерируемого элемента получить, или как то можно это сделать?

Comment: @MBo Тогда, пользуясь знанием питона, достаточно написать `sum(0 < x < 1 for x in a)` ;)

Comment: @Alexandr Добавить `enumerate` в `for`? Не совсем понял контекст вопроса

Comment: @CrazyElf   filter(lambda x,i : x == y[i] , a ) , где i номер итерации в filter, есть способ ее так передать? искал, не нашел ответ

Comment: @Alexandr Как-то так: `list(filter(lambda x: x[0] > 2 and x[1] < 5, enumerate(range(1,10))))`